# Change custom post taxonomy values from front-end

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, front-end

I'm developing a ticketing system which already has the custom post type for the tickets with a "status" taxonomy. I have the tickets displayed in a table on the front-end and the status column has the status values in a dropdown with the current status selected by default. How can I change the status taxonomy on the back-end based on the selection of the dropdown on the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

That would be achieved using the `wp_set_post_terms` function.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms

You could run an ajax request on the `change` event of the dropdown to either wp-admin/admin-ajax.php or a custom JSON API endpoint (preferred but more work) with a payload like this

```
{
    new_status: 123
    post_id: 321
}
```

Ensure 100% that the user that is logged in has authorization to modify the post

```
$post = get_post( filter_var( $_POST['post_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) );
if( /*Test User Auth*/ ){
    wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, [ 
        filter_var( $_POST['new_status'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) 
    ], 'status' );
}
```